# A question about the test statistic for testing the difference in two population proportions

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

For independent samples $X_1,\cdots,X_n $from $\textit{Bernoulli }(p_1)$
and $Y_1,\cdots,Y_m$ from $\textit{Bernoulli }(p_2)$,where $n$ and $m$ are large.
Then,the *Central Limit Theorem* tell us $\frac{\bar X_n-p_1}{\sqrt{\frac{p_1(1-p_1)}{n}}}$ converges in distribution to $\textit{Normal }(0,1)$ and $\frac{\bar Y_m-p_2}{\sqrt{\frac{p_2(1-p_2)}{m}}}$ converges in distribution to $\textit{Normal } (0,1)$.Can we get $\frac{(\bar X_n-\bar Y_m)-(p_1-p_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{p_1(1-p_1)}{n}+\frac{p_2(1-p_2)}{m}}} $ converges in distribution to $\textit{Normal }(0,1)$, when $n$ and $m$ are large enough?

I cannot find some conclusions said that if $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ and $Y_n$ converges in distribution to $Y$,then $X_n\pm Y_{n}$ converges in distribution to  $X\pm Y.$

In hypothesis test concerning the difference between two population proportions,
we consider two binomial populations with parameters $n$, $p_1$ and $m$, $p_2$, respectively, where $n$ and $m$ are large. Then, we are usually interested in testing hypotheses such as $$H_0: p_1 − p_2 \leq 0 \quad\textrm{versus}\quad H_1: p_1 − p_2 > 0 \quad (a)$$$$H_0: p_1 − p_2 \geq 0 \quad\textrm{ versus}\quad H_1: p_1 − p_2 < 0 \quad (b)$$$$H_0: p_1 − p_2 = 0 \quad\textrm{ versus}\quad H_1: p_1 − p_2 \ne 0 \quad (c)$$
Why we assume that
the test statistic $T= 
\frac{(\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2)-(p_1-p_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{p_1(1-p_1)}{n}+\frac{p_2(1-p_2)}{m}}}$,where $\hat{p}_1=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}$and $\hat{p}_2=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m}y_{k}$, is approximately distributed by the standard
normal $\textit{Normal }(0, 1)$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3235070/321264

Comment: @StubbornAtom: I am sorry, I fail to understand why we have $$\frac{\sqrt{n}\left((\hat p_1-\hat p_2)-(p_1-p_2)\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{p_1(1-p_1)}{\lambda}+\frac{p_2(1-p_2)}{1-\lambda}}}\stackrel{L}\longrightarrow N(0,1).$$ I cannot find some conclusions said that if $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ and $Y_n$ converges in distribution to $Y$,then $X_n\pm Y_{n}$ converges in distribution to  $X\pm Y.$

Comment: Talking to myself :A sequence of random variables $X_{n}$ is said to converge weakly or converge in distribution to a limit $X_{\infty}$(written $X_{n}\Rightarrow  X_{\infty}$).
If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent for $1 \le n \le \infty,X_{n}\Rightarrow X_{\infty}$ and $Y_{n}\Rightarrow Y_{\infty},$ then $X_{n}+Y_{n}\Rightarrow X_{\infty}+Y_{\infty}.$