# What's the difference between 'standard error' and 'estimated standard error'?

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-error

100 people are given a standard antibiotic to treat an infection and another 100 are given a new antibiotic. In the first group, 90 people recover; in the second group, 80 people recover. Let $p_1$ be the probability of recovery under the standard treatment and let $p_2$ be the probability of recovery under the new treatment. We are interested in estimating $θ=p_1-p_2$. Provide an estimate, an 95 percent confidence interval for θ. (for 95 percent confidence interval, $z_{0.5/2}$=2)

I got problem like this, since estimator is $\hat{\theta} =\hat{p_1} -\hat{p_2} = 0.9-0.8 = 0.1$. $\hat{se} $ is 0.05. I thought I solved the problem.

but what bothers me, someone said me that $p_1$, and $\hat{p_1}$ are the same. $se$ and $\hat{se}$(estimated standard error) are the same thing, What I thought til that day was I couldn't get real probability $p_1$ and $p_2$(since I can't know what distribution they follow), so get $\hat{p_1}$, and $\hat{p_2}$, and get $\hat{se}$.

Do I miss some concept?

Comment: How can $p_1$ and $\hat p_1$ be same? The unknown $p_1$ is estimated by $\hat p_1$. The standard error used is technically the estimated standard error because the s.e depends on the  unknown $p_1,p_2$. The CI is discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3188045/321264.

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything, just asking a sensible question. I address the difference between the standard error and the estimated standard error in my Answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $\hat\theta = \hat p_1 - \hat p_2 = 
\frac{90}{100} = \frac{80}{100} = 0.9 - 0.8 = 0.1.$

Then, $V(\hat p_1) = \frac{p_1(1-p_1)}{n},$
so $\hat V(\hat p_1) =\frac{\hat p_1(1-\hat p_1)}{n}.$
Similarly,
$\hat V(\hat p_2) =\frac{\hat p_2(1-\hat p_2)}{n}.$
By independence,
$V(\hat\theta) = V(\hat p_1) + V(\hat p_2),$ so
$$\hat V(\hat\theta) = \frac{\hat p_1(1-\hat p_1)}{n}+
\frac{\hat p_2(1-\hat p_2)}{n}$$
and
$$\widehat {SE}(\hat\theta) = \sqrt{\frac{\hat p_1(1-\hat p_1)}{n}+
\frac{\hat p_2(1-\hat p_2)}{n}}.$$

The theoretical standard error of $\hat \theta$
would use $p_i, i=1,2,$ but we do not know the true values of the $p_i.$ So we must use the *estimated*
standard error $\widehat{SE}(\hat\theta)$ (with $\hat p_i$s) instead.

Thus a 95% confidence interval for $\theta$ is
$\hat \theta \pm 1.96 \widehat{SE}(\hat \theta).$

Notice that *two* approximations are involved: (1) assuming that $\hat\theta$ is approximately normal, justifying the use of $1.96$ and (2) using the estimated
standard error instead of the unknown theoretical
standard error.

Thus the confidence interval
must be regarded as valid for large $n$ and not
necessarily for small or moderate $n.$ I wonder if $n=100$ is large enough for the "95%" confidence
interval to have the promised 95% coverage probability.

In making confidence intervals for a single binomial
proportion $p,$ it has become standard practice to
use Agresti-Coull CIs, which use estimates that
"append 2 successes and 2 failures" to the data.
(This amounts to a 'trick' that closely matches
a more complicated and more accurate form of CI.)

To get a CI for $\theta$ in the current case, it
might be better to use $\tilde p_1 = 92/104$ instead
of $\hat p_1,$ to use $\tilde p_2 = 82/104$ instead
of $\hat p_2,$ and to use denominators 104 instead of 100 in $\widehat{SE}(\hat \theta).$

For the standard formula above I get the CI $(0.002, .0.198),$ same as you got, and for the adjusted CI I have $(-0.0035, 0.1958).$

A basic parametric 95% bootstrap CI is $(0.00, 0.20),$
as shown below. There is not much difference among
the results from the three methods.

```
set.seed(2020)
P1 = rbinom(10^4, 100, .9)/100
P2 = rbinom(10^4, 100, .8)/100
TH = P1 - P2
q = quantile(TH, c(.025,.975)); q
 2.5% 97.5% 
  0.0   0.2 

hist(TH, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
  abline(v = q, col="red")
```

[image]